# I m installing mythril and this is happening

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I m installing mythril and this is happening. Command in windows 10 into virtualenv prompt. I apologize that part of the output is in portuguese.

```
pip install mythril


Building wheel for pyethash (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      cl : Linha de comando warning D9002 : ignorando op‡Æo desconhecida '-std=gnu99'
      internal.c
      cl : Linha de comando warning D9002 : ignorando op‡Æo desconhecida '-std=gnu99'
      io.c
      cl : Linha de comando warning D9002 : ignorando op‡Æo desconhecida '-std=gnu99'
      io_win32.c
      c1: fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo fonte: 'src/libethash/io_win32.c': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyethash
  Running setup.py clean for pyethash
Failed to build pyethash
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyethash, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: This kind of error is often caused by an incompatibility between your Python version and the package's version. Which version of Python 3 do you have, and which version of `mythril` are you trying to install?